# What is this informative window?

Tags: discussion

**EDIT**: This question already has an answer at [Stack Exchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165006/271002).

---

An [answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/33176/10493) to a question has a window which I have not seen on other SE sites, nor it is present in the body of the answer:

[image]

- How has it been added? (automatically? by a mod/high-rep user?)
- is this a standard SE feature, available on other sites in the network?

Comment: Related: [What are these notices under my post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165006/271002)

Comment: @Loong: That's pretty much an answer.

Comment: Yes it is, unfortunately I cannot mark it as a duplicate. I will update my question with the link

Comment: I'm expanding that link into an answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a hat-tip to @Loong, there is a question on Meta Stack Exchange that addresses this. [What are these notices under my post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165006/what-are-these-notices-under-my-post)

Specifically to address your questions:

- Added by moderators. (I wish it could be added by high-rep users, but I don't think it can.)
- The feature is standard, but the selection of post notices is site-specific. (The text choices is managed by the Stack Exchange team, not mods.)
- Other choices on Skeptics.SE include warnings about original research, current (i.e. still rapidly changing) events, theoretical answers, etc.